# Is this Monoid Finitely Generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, monoid, finitely-generated

Let $G$ be a finitely generated  abelian group, $H\leq G$, and $S = \{g_1, \dots, g_n\}$ be some finite generating set for $G$.

Let $G’$ be the set of negative-free linear combinations of elements of $S$. i.e. $G’ = \{a_1g_1 + \dots + a_ng_n | a_1,\dots, a_n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, and let $H’= G’ \cap H$.

Is $H’$ finitely generated as a monoid i.e. is there some finite subset of $H’$, $S’$ such that every element of $H’$ is a nonnegative linear combination of $S’$?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It's a good question. I hope that it doesn't get closed. Have you looked at some examples already?

Comment: First things first: are submonoids of finitely generated commutative monoids also finitely generated? If not, what is an example?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: A counterexample is the submonoid of $\mathbb{N}^2$ generated by $(1,n)$ for all $n$.  That can’t give a counterexample for this question though since it isn’t closed under subtraction.

Answer (score 4):

The answer appears to be yes.

$\textbf{Lemma:}$ Let $A$ be a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{N}^n$ equipped with the partial order $(a_1, \ldots ,a_n)\leq(b_1, \ldots, b_n)$ iff $a_i\leq b_i$ for all $i=1, \ldots ,n$. Then $A$ has only finitely many minimial elements.

Let us prove this by induction on $n$. For $n=1$ this is just the well-ordering principle. Assume the lemma holds for $n\geq 1$ and let $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}^{n+1}$ be non-empty. Clearly $A$ has some minimal element, say $\mathbf{x}=(x_1, \ldots ,x_{n+1})\in A$. Then any other minimal element of $A$ must have at least one coordinate that is less than the corresponding $\mathbf{x}$ coordinate. More precisely, any other minimal element of $A$ is contained in the union
$$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}\bigcup\limits_{j=0}^{x_i-1} \{(a_1, \ldots ,a_{n+1})\in A: a_i=j\}.$$
Moreover, a minimal element of $A$ is in particular a minimal element of the corresponding $\{(a_1, \ldots ,a_{n+1})\in A: a_i=j\}$ set to which it belongs and by the induction hypothesis there are only finitely many of these. Since the union is finite it follows that $A$ has only finitely many minimal elements. $\square$

Now we use the lemma to show that $H'$ is finitely generated. Consider $$\bar{H}=\{(a_1, \ldots, a_n)\in \mathbb{N}^n\backslash\{\mathbf{0}\} : \sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_ig_i\in H\}.$$ This set has finitely many minimal elements, say $\mathbf{a_1}, \ldots ,\mathbf{a_m}$. Let $h_1, \ldots h_m\in H'$ be the corresponding group elements, more precisely, $h_i=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_{i, j}g_j$ where $\mathbf{a_i}=(a_{i, 1}, \ldots ,a_{i, n})$.

We claim that the $h_i$'s generate $H'$ as a monoid so let $h=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_ig_i\in H'\backslash\{e\}$. If $\mathbf{a}=(a_1, \ldots ,a_n)$ is a minimal element of $\bar{H}$ then $h$ is one of the $h_i$'s and we are done. If not, then there is a minimal element, say $\mathbf{a_{i_1}}$, with $\mathbf{a_{i_1}}<\mathbf{a}$. Since $H$ is a subgroup, we have $\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{a_{i_1}}\in \bar{H}$. If this element is minimal, say $\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{a_{i_1}}=\mathbf{a_{i_2}}$ then $h=h_{i_1}+h_{i_2}$ and we are done. If not, we continue as before. Eventually the process must terminate and we obtain that $h=\sum\limits_{j=1}^k h_{i_j}$ for some $i_j$'s.

Comment: Your lemma is known as [Dickson's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson%27s_lemma). See Kruskal, Joseph B. (1972). [The theory of well-quasi-ordering: A frequently discovered concept.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316572900635?via%3Dihub) Journal of Combinatorial Theory. Series A. 13 (3): 298 for related results. The [graph minor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robertson–Seymour_theorem) is a further (and much more difficult) extension of [Kruskal's tree theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_tree_theorem).